# Scala under MSys2 - failure to initialize terminal

Tags: java, windows, scala, msys2

My environment is Windows 10 x64/Scala 2.11.7/Msys2 latest.

When running Scala from MSys2 console, I see the following:

```
$ scala
[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32
    at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode(WindowsSupport.java:50)
    at jline.WindowsTerminal.getConsoleMode(WindowsTerminal.java:204)
    at jline.WindowsTerminal.init(WindowsTerminal.java:82)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:158)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:229)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:221)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:209)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.JLineConsoleReader.<init>(JLineReader.scala:61)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.InteractiveReader.<init>(JLineReader.scala:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$instantiate$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:865)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$instantiate$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:862)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$mkReader$1(ILoop.scala:871)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ILoop.scala:875)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ILoop.scala:875)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$15.apply(ILoop.scala:875)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$15.apply(ILoop.scala:875)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.map(Stream.scala:418)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.chooseReader(ILoop.scala:875)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply(ILoop.scala:916)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:916)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:911)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:911)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:911)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:74)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)

Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

When running it from cmd.exe, it works as expected. To debug the issue, I tried the following Scala program:

```
object Test extends App {
    println(org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode)
}
```

When run from Msys2, it produces the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path]
    at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:182)
    at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:140)
    at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32.<clinit>(Kernel32.java:37)
    at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode(WindowsSupport.java:50)
    at Test$.delayedEndpoint$Test$1(Test.scala:5)
    at Test$delayedInit$body.apply(Test.scala:1)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at Test$.main(Test.scala:1)
    at Test.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:65)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

What I tried and it didn't work:

- Some threads on the internet mention that it might be caused by missing VC2008 runtime, so I made sure that I have it both for x64 and x86.
- Extracting jansi.dll from scala/lib/jline-2.12.1.jar and putting it in my working directory (with "." included in java.library.path).
- Starting with a fresh MSys2 home directory.
- running bash --login -i from cmd.exe (same error when running scala)
- trying 32-bit and 64-bit JREs

One more thing: the issue doesn't affect sbt; for example, running "sbt console" gives me a working Scala command line, albeit of version 2.10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the name clash between the `scala` shell script in `scala/bin` directory and `scala.bat` in the same directory. Msys2 runs the shell script, while cmd.exe runs the batch file. Apparently, the shell script is not suited for Msys2, which causes the error that I witnessed. Issuing `cmd //c scala.bat` from MSys2 results in a functional Scala command line.

It is also trivial to edit the `scala` shell script to support MSys2: https://gist.github.com/kirillkh/a9ba2e00ef2e901f13bf

I have opened a pull request with this change on the GitHub: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4674

Comment: Hi, I also encounter this problem `Could not initialize class org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32` with cygwin and cmd on Windows7 x64. I do not have a scala or sbt installation on my machine, I only use gradlew's (2.8) scala plugin. I do not have, can't find any scala.bat file or scala shell script. Do you have any idea how to fix that error in such a situation?

Comment: Well, there must be a scala shell script that is being run if you're getting this error message. Try issuing 'which scala' command and see what that gives, or searching more extensively. I am not familiar with gradelw.